# Acer synaptics touchpad stops working randomly

Tags: windows-10, synaptics-touchpad, touch

I have an Acer Aspire VN7-791G. I am using the latest Windows 10 version (1909 18363.720), and keeping it up to date. But my touchpad stops working randomly and this freezes my computer for 1-2 sec.

Also, when I look in Device Manager, it keeps refreshing. Sometimes the Synaptics section is hiding, and then it shows again. It is not related to cables or other physical issue, because I tried testing in Ubuntu and the touchpad works well.

[gif-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycvOu.gif)
[gif-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bnzP.gif)

Comment: +1 for testing in alternative OS (Ubuntu). BTW, press the Windows key, type "winver" and hit the Enter key, to get the exact version and build, and add that to your original question.

Comment: Have you tried to install any drivers from Acer's website : Windows x64 https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/5615;-;Aspire%20VN7-791G There are 2015 drivers there, that might help, I would uninstall the existing ones first then, without rebooting, install the downloaded drivers. Also, if your Device Manager keeps resetting you may have a loose cable attached. You might need to under-the-hood, _remove the keyboard_, and have a look.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thank you for suggestion. I added build number.

Comment: @vssher as i said, it not related cables, i tested on ubuntu and it is working. Also tried officical drivers from acer website. And it is related touchpad, not keyboard. Because, when i deactivate by pressing fn+f7 (it deactivates touchpad) device manager stops keep refreshing.

Comment: BTW, do a complete virus scan in Windows with an alternate AV, such as free Malwarebytes. There could be a malicious program running in the background, using CPU cycles, e.g., a Bitcoin miner.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik i am using fresh installation.